# Стоит ли реализовывать функции в заголовочных файлах?

Tags: c, функции

Однажды при консультации с коллегами насчёт проекта я получил шквал критики в свой адрес за то что объявляю (описываю прототип) и реализую функции в заголовочном файле. По мнению критиков реализацию функции следует помещать в файлы .c. Актуально ли такое решение учитывая что мне придётся использовать одни и те же функции в разных файлах?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Для того, чтобы сделать что-то подобное в языке С необходимо предпринимать определенные сознательные усилия, далеко выходящие за пределы просто "определения функций в заголовочном файле". Каким образом вы это делаете? Вы все свои функции объявляете как `static`? Как `inline`? Как `static inline`? Еще как-то? О чем именно речь? Приведите пример.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если кто-либо определяет обычную функцию (без спецификаторов `static` или `inline` ) в хедере, то это говорит об одном из двух:

- Либо он пытается сделать что-то очень хитрое, например он подразумевает, что этот файл будет включаться только в ограниченный набор специально подготовленных `*.c`-файлов и затем функции «настраиваются» макросами в итоге получая некие «шаблоны для бедных» (хотя обычно в таких случаях используется другое расширение, например `*.inc`).
- Либо он безграмотный новичок, который не понимает, что при включении этого хедера в две различных единицы трансляции это вызовет ошибку линковки.

Второе встречается куда-чаще чем первое.

Если функции определены в хедере как `static`, то это опять же одно из двух:

- Либо программист с полным пониманием того что делает захотел, чтобы в каждой единице транляции, куда включается данный файл была отдельная копия данной функции.
- Либо тот же безграмотный новичок просто дописал `static` «чтобы заработало», не понимая последствий, например, что это наверняка увеличит размер исполняемого файла.

Если же это сознательно объявленная `inline`-функция, то всё верно — почти наверняка реализацию следует держать в хедере, иначе компилятор не сможет её встроить.

Надо помнить, что в Си в отличии от C++ компилятор не будет самостоятельно выбирать, в какой объектный файл пристроить функцию, поэтому надо дополнительно объявить её ровно в одном файле реализации без спецификатора `inline`, иначе это чревато ошибкой линковки.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, начнем с того, что тогда вам нужно объявлять функции как `inline`.

В вашем подходе есть и плюсы, и минусы.

Основной плюс - компилятор может встроить функцию, у него больше возможностей для оптимизации.

Основной минус - получается компиляция большого объема кода, что в больших проектах может замедлить компиляцию, ну и тянуть заголовочных файлов явно потребуется большее количество...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: *"нужно объявлять функции как `inline`"* Недавно попробовал использовать его в С, оказалось он очень занятно работает. Отдельное определение функции в .c-файле все равно нужно; компилятор использует его, когда решает не инлайнить функцию (например на ГЦЦ при дебажной сборке - всегда...).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в моей практике с `static inline` в gcc никогда подобных проблем не возникало. Вообще, не вижу причин, почему для `static` функции даже без `inline`, определенной в .h с правильными guards могут возникнуть проблемы

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в данном случае в `.c` файле нужно не *определение*, а *объявление* ;)

Comment: @avp, это не очень хорошая практика — в каждой единице трансляции будет своя копия функции и они ни как не убираются на стадии линковки, в итоге это раздувает бинарник, когда они не встраиваются... к тому же для `static`-не-`inline`-функций gcc на -Wall будет верещать о том, что они не используются...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я не утверждал, что это хорошая практика, я написал про проблемы (что со `static` их не видел). Понятно, что в .h файлах имеет смысл держать (распространять вместо библиотеки) код, про который предполагается, что обычно он будет  использован в одной единице трансляции. Ну а вопли компилятора (конечно, не без трудозатрат) затыкаются #ifdef-ами